# Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

SO, I am trying create a simple regex that matches the following string:

```
<PRE>><A HREF="../cgi-bin/hgTracks?hgsid=160564920&db=hg18&position=chrX:33267175-33267784&hgPcrResult=pack">chrX:33267175-33267784</A> 610bp TGATGTTTGGCGAGGAACTC GCAGAGTTTGAAGAGCTCGG
TGATGTTTGGCGAGGAACTCtactattgttacacttaggaaaataatcta
atccaaaggctttgcatctgtacagaagagcgagtagatactgaaagaga
tttgcagatccactgttttttaggcaggaagaatgctcgttaaatgcaaa
cgctgctctggctcatgtgtttgctccgaggtataggttttgttcgactg
acgtatcagatagtcagagtggttaccacaccgacgttgtagcagctgca
taataaatgactgaaagaatcatgttaggcatgcccacctaacctaactt
gaatcatgcgaaaggggagctgttggaattcaaatagactttctggttcc
cagcagtcggcagtaatagaatgctttcaggaagatgacagaatcaggag
aaagatgctgttttgcactatcttgatttgttacagcagccaacttattg
gcatgatggagtgacaggaaaaacagctggcatggaaggtaggattatta
aagctattacatcattacaaatacaattagaagctggccatgacaaagca
tatgtttgaacaagcagctgttggtagctggggtttgttgCCGAGCTCTT
CAAACTCTGC
</PRE>
```

I have created the following regex:

```
<PRE>[.|[\n]]*</PRE>
```

yet it won't match the string above. Does anyone have a solution to this conundrum and perhaps a reasoning as toward why this doesn't work.

Sorry about the formatting of this question.

Comment: Are you trying to just match that exact string type, or do you want to pull pieces of the string out?

Comment: You have newlines in your string, so don't you need some "match across multiple lines" flag?

Comment: what dont you understand? he just wants the string between and including the <PRE> tags

Comment: Were you attempting to match the string with the `<PRE>` tag in it, or was that only meant to be used for formatting?

Comment: I tried to reformat this as best I could... The original was really confusingly formatted. Hope I didn't destroy the original meaning.

Comment: @every_answer: is there really a need to be so snarky?  I was clarifying the OP's question; that doesn't make me an idiot.

Comment: SO here is the clarification: I need it to match the string the includes the <PRE> and ends with the </PRE>. Doesn't my regex expression make sense?

Comment: there is random junk before the pre and after the pre that isn't important

Comment: wasnt directed at you bach, to bcarter

Answer (score 2):

Stop trying to parse HTML using regexes. You can't do it (robustly). There's a reason there's this [famous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to parse HTML, please use lxml, as Hank proposed.

But for this regex to work, you need to change the `[]` to `()`. A `|` inside square brackets is interpreted as the symbol '|' and not as an OR operator.

Another option is to use the flag that's called [DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), which makes the dot operator match anything, including a newline. This way the regex becomes very simple:

```
m = re.match(r'<PRE>(.*)</PRE>', input_string, re.DOTALL)
m.group(1)
```

outputs the string inside the PRE, without the `< PRE >`and`< /PRE >` themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that inside `[]`'s the `.` is a period, not a match-anything dot; the `|` is a pipe, not an `or`; and the `[` and `]` are braces, not character-class creators -- in other words, the non-backslash special symbols lose their specialness.

What you will want to do is this:

```
m = re.search(r'(<PRE>.*</PRE>)', input_string, re.DOTALL)
m.group(1)
```

`.search()` will look everywhere in the string for the match (`.match()` only checks the beginning of the string), and `re.DOTALL` (`or re.S`) will have the `.` match newlines as well.

If you don't want the `<PRE>` and `</PRE>` tags included, move the parentheses to surround the `.*`.